# Spring scheduled task cron expression validation

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I'm writing a scheduled task that need to run every 1st Saturday of each month.
I came up with this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 23 1-7 * SAT")
// Runs on 1st Saturday of each month at 23:00
public void CleanUpScheduledTask() {
}
```

How did I come uo with this:

`0 0 23` means at 11:00 PM everyday

`1-7 *` means between 1-7 every month

`SAT` Saturdays

How do you suggest to make sure that the above expression is valid? how I test such functionalities?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Building Cron Expression**

Using the Spring cron job expression

`@Scheduled(cron = "[Seconds] [Minutes] [Hours] [Day of month] [Month] [Day of week] [Year]")`

***NB year field is optional***

- `#` used to specify day of the week and week the task should start.

  eg first Saturday of every month(`7#1`)
- `?` represents no specific value and can be used in either the day of month or day of week field
- `*` represents all values

hence cron expression becomes

`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 23 ? * 7#1")`

**2. Testing Cron Job**

- use `Awaitility dependency`

  ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
       <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  ```

-using `Spring Integration testing`

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(CleanScheduler.class)
public class CleanSchedulerUnitTest {
    @Autowired
    private CleanScheduler cleanScheduler;

    @Test
    void cleanUpScheduledTaskShouldReturnSuccess() {
       //Act
        cleanScheduler.cleanUpScheduledTask();
      //Assertions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online Cron generator like https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html to generate cron expressions or to describe what you posted.

0 0 0,23 ? * 7#1 * should be described and run At second:00, at minute:00, at 00 am and 23pm, on the 1st Saturday of the month, every month.